# How can I call a class' method inside one of that class' method's anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, class

I have the following:

```
class Button_Event {
    add_click() {
        this.button_jquery_object.on('click', function(e){
            this.add_loading();

            run_function_by_name(this.ajax_callback).done(function() {
                this.remove_loading();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

But when I run it, the following error occurs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.add_loading is not a function
```

...and rightfully so. I'm trying to call a class' method inside an anonymous function. I feel as if I shouldn't do this but **I need to do this**. How can this be done?

I believe I'm looking to somehow enforce the "this" scope on my anonymous' functions body too.

Comment: To use this, you must assign the object "this" to a different variable in the parent function

Comment: Where is the "add loading" method defined

Comment: @Minan The `add_loading` is defined inside the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional solution: store `this` in a local variable

```
add_click() {
    const self = this;
    this.button_jquery_object.on('click', function(e){
        self.add_loading();
    });
}
```

---

Modern solution: use an arrow function, which automatically bind `this` from context

```
add_click() {
    this.button_jquery_object.on('click', (e) => {
        this.add_loading();
    });
}
```

---

Strange solution: manually bind `this` to the function

```
add_click() {
    this.button_jquery_object.on('click', function(e){
        this.add_loading();
    }.bind(this));
}
```